# Android: How to do instrumented tests with mocked locations?

Tags: android, location, instrumented-test

For instrumented tests of location services I need mocked locations. But the current concept from Android seems to be not very practical.

In order to be allowed to use mocked locations the test-package also needs the permission `android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION`. When added to a debug-manifest I get the hint, that this permission will only be granted to System-Apps. I have to add `tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"` to the permission to suppress this warning. IMHO it makes no sense to issue such a warning for a property that is necessary for such tests.

Then I need to select this test-package as mock-location provider for the test-device. Acceptable for a manual test. But do I really have to manually select this setting for every device I want to test my code on? (What about this firebase-test on a farm of test devices? There I can not make this setting.)

And what if I have more than one app that tests mocked location? Currently I can not test both packages on the same device.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Architect your app to isolate your location API (e.g., `LocationManager`) to a single class that implements an interface. Using dependency inversion (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.) or other mechanisms, have your tests work using a mock or fake implementation of the interface. Now you are in complete control over the location data, without having to deal with the platform considerations described in your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare Definititively a path to follow. But my ultimate goal here is to be able to test if my app receives location-updates in the background. A task that will not be achievable with that strategy. There I need the original functionality.